# Returning specific data combination from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL:

`Races` - which comprises `raceid`, `racedate`, `racetime`, `course`

`Runners` - which comprises `horseid`, `raceid`, `horse`, `jockey`, `trainer`

How do I create a query that returns, for a specified `racedate`, the `racetime`/`course`/`horse` where a `jockey` has only one ride at that `course` and that `horse` is the `trainer`'s only `horse` at that `course` on that `racedate`?

I have zero knowledge of SQL apart from simple queries!

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You do a join between the tables and two subqueries: one that returns the jockes with only one ride, and another that returns trainers with only one horse.

Comment: @Barmar - but the trainer may have more than one horse running that day, just not at that particular course.

Comment: You would add `WHERE course='X'`

Comment: Question: "only horse at that course" (ha rhyme), does this mean on the specific `racedate` or ever?  For example, trainer A has Horse B here yesterday and Horse C last week.

Comment: @David Starkey On the specific racedate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note... I'm shooting from the hip. You may find small bugs or logical errors in the code below. I am also not a MySQL expert, so I might have made an assumption which is true for most DBMSes, but not true for MySQL specifically. Take with a grain of salt and always test thoroughly.*

I'll take your question as an example of how to think through your requirements:

> ***How do I create a query that returns, for a specified racedate,***

Let's start here. You need all races for a specified race date, which is going to involve selecting rows from your `Races` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Races
WHERE racedate = '2010-10-01'
```

> ***the racetime/course/horse***

This is simply the data you want to select, but not all of it is in your `Races` table. You can get the `racetime` and `course` from `Races`, but the `horse` must come from runners. So the next step is to join your `Races` table to the `Runners` table:

```
SELECT Races.racetime
     , Races.course
     , Runners.horse
FROM Races
   , Runners
WHERE racedate = '2010-10-01'
    AND Runners.raceid = Races.raceid
```

> ***where a jockey has only one ride at that course***

This one is a bit trickier. What you need to do at this point is put your current query on hold and start a new query to check to see how many races a particular jockey ran at a particular race track on a particular day. We can get `jockey` from the `Runners` table, but we need to join back to the `Races` table to get the `racedate` and `course`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Runners
   , Races
WHERE Races.raceid = Runners.raceid
  AND Runners.jockey = 'jockeyName'
  AND Races.course = 'courseName'
  AND Races.racedate = '2010-10-01'
```

We now have a query which will give us the number of races a jockey made. We can now incorporate this back into our original query as a subquery, getting the `jockey`, `course` and `racedate` from the parent query (I use aliases on the subquery tables so as not to confuse those tables with the parent tables, since they are the same):

```
SELECT Races.racetime
     , Races.course
     , Runners.horse
FROM Races
  , Runners
WHERE racedate = '2010-10-01'
  AND Runners.raceid = Races.raceid
  AND (    SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Runners AS sub_run
              , Races AS sub_race
           WHERE sub_race.raceid = sub_run.raceid
             AND sub_run.jockey = Runners.jockey
             AND sub_race.course = Races.course
             AND sub_race.racedate = Races.racedate
      ) = 1
```

> ***and that horse is the trainer's only horse at that course***

This is going to be yet another subquery, as you might guess at this point:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Runners.horsename)
FROM Runners
   , Races
WHERE Races.raceid = Runners.raceid
  AND Runners.trainer = 'trainerName'
  AND Races.course = 'courseName'
  AND Races.racedate = '2010-10-01'
```

This query includes "COUNT(DISTINCT ...)" to ensure that we are only counting unique horse names and not the same horse multiple times (multiple races, etc).

```
SELECT Races.racetime
     , Races.course
     , Runners.horse
FROM Races
  , Runners
WHERE Races.racedate = '2010-10-01'
  AND Runners.raceid = Races.raceid
  AND (    SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Runners AS sub_run
              , Races AS sub_race
           WHERE sub_race.raceid = sub_run.raceid
             AND sub_run.jockey = Runners.jockey
             AND sub_race.course = Races.course
             AND sub_race.racedate = Races.racedate
      ) = 1
  AND (    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sub_run.horsename)
           FROM Runners AS sub_run
              , Races AS sub_race
           WHERE sub_race.raceid = sub_run.raceid
             AND sub_run.trainer = Runners.trainer
             AND sub_race.course = Races.course
             AND sub_race.racedate = Races.racedate
      ) = 1
```

(You can reuse the subquery table aliases in subsequent subqueries - because each subquery executes in a different context, the DBMS will not be confused)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to break this down.

I have followed everything down to the last sub-query but don't quite understand that.

I have edited the original query to clarify that I am looking for the trainer to have only one horse at that course ON THAT DAY, rather than having no regard to the racedate.

Comment: @phrenetic - yes, I saw your comment. I've already edit the query to reflect that.

Comment: The second subquery returns more than one row (I guess because of the Group By statement) which means that MySQL throws an error

Comment: @phrenetic - Oops... you are right. That should have been a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` without the `GROUP BY`. Edited.